# Datagridview copy and paste on combobox column

Tags: c#, copy-paste, datagridtemplatecolumn, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am working on a datagridview control. I have added a combobox column to it and populating it from a datatable as;

```
DataTable datatable1 = new DataTable();   
datatable1.Columns.Add("DisplayMember");   
datatable1.Columns.Add("ValueMember");   

//*** For loop to load datatable1 with values ***   

combobox1.DataSource = datatable1;   
combobox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";   
combobox1.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
```

Now when data is populated I am trying to select a record from combobox column and using Copy/Paste as Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V. But it is giving me an error as

> The data you pasted is in the wrong format for the cell..

I could figured out that it is because of DisplayMember and ValueMember properties. But I can't remove this as well.

If I set DisplayMember and ValueMember to the same value then it works fine. But I have to keep those fields different.

Does anyone knows how to resolve this error ?

Thanks in advance
Vijay

Comment: Copying What and pasting where ?

Comment: let's say I have 5 rows. I am copying combobox column value from row 1 and pasting it in other 4 rows of the same column.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to paste in data in grid, i also works on dropdowns, if it is the values that are pasted...
The cast command is from System.Linq.

```
void Ctrl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) || (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert))
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = e.Handled = EditAppend(ClipboardAsDataRow);
    }
}


public bool EditAppend(IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
{
    try
    {
        // whatever is your datasourse... 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable;
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            dt.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, LoadOption.Upsert);
        }
        return true;    
    }
    catch ()
    {
        return false;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Get Clipboard as DataRows
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<DataRow> ClipboardAsDataRow
{
get
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (iData == null || !iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();

        string table = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        foreach (string row in value.Split("\n".ToCharArray()))
        {
            dt.LoadDataRow(row.Split("\r\x09".ToCharArray()), true);
        }
        return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How should I apply it to my current example ?

Comment: Sorry, this code does not what you where asking for.
However, trapping the Ctrl+V AND Ctrl-C, and processing the clipboard is still the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Detect that the cell you are pasting into is a combo box, and set it appropriately.

Example:

```
if (oCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell tmp = oCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
    if (tmp.Items.Contains(sCells[i]))
    {
        tmp.Value = tmp.Items[tmp.Items.IndexOf(sCells[i])];
    }
}
```